# VMWare Workstation Ubuntu 18.04 - Minikube: Error creating VM:

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, vmware, minikube

I'm attempting to run Minikube in a VMWare Workstation guest, running Ubuntu 18.04.

`kubectl version` results in:

`Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"12", GitVersion:"v1.12.0", GitCommit:"0ed33881dc4355495f623c6f22e7dd0b7632b7c0", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-09-27T17:05:32Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}`

`minikube version` results in:

```
minikube version: v0.29.0
```

I have enabled Virtualize Intel VT-x/EPT or AMD-V/RVI on the VMWare guest configuration. I have 25GB of hard drive space. Yet, regardless of how I attempt to start Minikube, I get the following error:

```
Starting local Kubernetes v1.10.0 cluster...
Starting VM...
E1005 11:02:32.495579    5913 start.go:168] Error starting host: Error creating host: Error creating machine: Error in driver during machine creation: Error creating VM: virError(Code=1, Domain=10, Message='internal error: qemu unexpectedly closed the monitor: 2018-10-05T09:02:29.926633Z qemu-system-x86_64: error: failed to set MSR 0x38d to 0x0
qemu-system-x86_64: /build/qemu-11gcu0/qemu-2.11+dfsg/target/i386/kvm.c:1807: kvm_put_msrs: Assertion `ret == cpu->kvm_msr_buf->nmsrs' failed.').

 Retrying.
```

Commands I've tried:

```
minikube start --vm-driver=kvm2

minikube start --vm-driver=kvm

minikube start --vm-driver=none
```

All result in the same thing.

I notice that on the Ubuntu guest, the network will shortly disconnect and re-connect when I run `minikube start`. Is it a problem with the network driver? How would I debug this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently getting virtualbox as a dependency to use as a vm driver works.

`sudo apt install virtualbox virtualbox-ext-pack`

`minikube start --vm-driver=virtualbox`

Now results in:

```
Starting local Kubernetes v1.10.0 cluster...
Starting VM...
Getting VM IP address...
Moving files into cluster...
Downloading kubeadm v1.10.0
Downloading kubelet v1.10.0
Finished Downloading kubelet v1.10.0
Finished Downloading kubeadm v1.10.0
Setting up certs...
Connecting to cluster...
Setting up kubeconfig...
Starting cluster components...
```

etc

Answer (score 2):

I observed a similar issue on Ubuntu 18.04.1 VM (Intel), the solution I found is:

1. Run this from the console:

```
$ sudo cat > /etc/modprobe.d/qemu-system-x86.conf << EOF
options kvm_intel nested=1 enable_apicv=n
options kvm ignore_msrs=1
EOF
```

2. Reboot the VM